# Prevent apps from closing

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I am currently writing a parental control app and one of the features that I want to implement is to prevent apps from closing.
I am not looking to damage the computer! only temporarily prevent closing apps on the computer. I am working on a windows machine, is there any way to implement it? (side note, I am also writing the code in python)

Comment: On what basis or instance you want to close the app? Are you asking about any timeout method or user-input method (e.g. click)?

Comment: I want to prevent closing any app on the system from being terminated when the little x on the top of the app is pressed and/or when the app is terminated in task manager

Comment: Who do you want to prevent from closing the app? The system administrative on any system can close anything.

Comment: I am the system admin